# Rails Nested Attributes for a Model not directly associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a feature whereby several models (3+) will have images or documents associated with them. To reduce duplicate code I have created a single model `MediaUploads` which `belongs_to :user` resulting in a user `has_many :media_uploads`.

The `MediaUploads` table stores the User ID alongside file information, nothing specific to any other model. Whereby each model that requires an image has the association `has_one :media_upload` and a reference column on their DB table `t.integer "media_uploads_id`. I think this is an appropriate way to achieve this however I am running into a few problems.

The above setup works fine if a User is managing their media however I am struggling to make this work using nested forms. An example, `Post` which may require a `MediaUpload` may look like this:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :media_upload` now if I use byebug and get the `params` I can see the file details was included `ActionController::Parameters {"media_uploads"=>{"filename"=>#<...` but using `post_params` I can see that it was not permitted. I have added this to the strong params like so: `...post attributes..., media_upload_attributes: [ :filename ]` - I have also tried just media_upload and media_uploads.

My Googling keeps bringing me back to changing the `new` method to something like:

`@post = Post.new
 @post.build_media_upload`

which gives me the error `unknown attribute 'post_id' for MediaUpload.` - presumably because the `build` needs to happen from the user, considering the user_id is referenced by `MediaUpload`

Would anybody be able to give me some pointers?

**UPDATE**

This is what I have currently that is not working:

In my **Post.rb** I have the following

```
has_one :media_upload
accepts_nested_attributes_for :media_upload
```

In my **_form.html.erb** I have

```
<%= f.fields_for :media_uploads do |h| %>
  <%= h.file_field :filename, class:"btn-file" %>
<% end %>
```

In my **Controller** I have

```
..post params..., media_uploads_attributes: [ :filename ])
```

I can see the data when using the terminal command `params` however `post_params` states the following: `Unpermitted parameter: media_uploads`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be plural in strong params, because Rails looks at the database table, not your model and database tables are named in plural.

So result should be:

`...post attributes..., media_uploads_attributes: [ :filename ]`

Comment: Thanks J.D however it didn't solve my problem. I have updated my question with my exact setup that is causing issues (including your changes)

Comment: I havent worked with `file_field` much before, but I think you dont need `f.fields_for` block. Your error says that this is exactly what is not being permitted. Try simply `f. file_field :filename, class:"btn-file"`

Comment: or if you are creating a new :media_uploads object's record in this form, you should build it. If directly in form, so something like `<%= f.fields_for :media_uploads, post.media_uploads.build do |h| %>`

Comment: Thanks J.D I have tried both of your suggestions and I am getting the same errors. I have used this type of setup on another project and I can not spot a difference between the two. I am using Rails 5 on this project - does that change anything?

Comment: btw - you might need to add `belongs_to :post, optional: true` for MediaUpload (and of course post_id to MediaUpload db schema), and maybe accept double nested attributes in strong params

Comment: just thought about it a bit more - never faced such situation and just now completely released it - you can't get MediaUpload attributes from the Post controller, since Post doesent have any relation with it. User has. So maybe strong params should be something like `...post attributes..., users_attributes: [  ...., media_uploads_attributes: [ :filename ]]` But then, might need triple nested fields in form, what is not recommended. If so, I think you should keep it simple and add associations to every model as in docs

Comment: I think you are correct J.D - I found myself spending far too much time on it. My intention was for users to essentially have a media library that can be used by several models - Users can add media when they create records for each model. Like you said there is no direct association between Post and MediaUpload and I didn't want to have references to multiple models within the MediaUpload table. What I have done is created a new Media Model / Table for each Model that requires media - similar to the examples and that works - albeit less elegantly. Thank you for all of your efforts!

Comment: Very nice, happy it helped!